# ¿Que componente utilizar para esta lista desplegable?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: ¿Cual es el mejor componente para realizar esta lista personalizada?]

Necesito realizar el siguiente componente para mi aplicación y tengo la duda que utilizar si un listview o un ExpandableListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un listview con tu layout personalizado sería una buena idea.

También deberías echar un ojo a la idea de poner un recyclerview con [cardviews](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=es-419).

Comment: Gracias Brugui, voy a mirar el recyclerview con cardviews. Imagino que para expandir el listview se realizará una llamada en algun método con listener para mostrar los controles de reproducción.